# Use of "that" in "the meaning is that of a noun"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I don't understand "the meaning is that of a noun" here

> In compound nouns using the gerund, it is clear that **the meaning is that of a noun**, not of a continuous verb

I don't understand the structure of this fragment. Please explain how it works.

Comment: Please give more context

Comment: ***this, that, these, those*** are "determiners / pronouns" (they "stand in" for actual nouns). In your context, *the meaning is **the meaning** of a noun*. In contexts like this, the word ***that*** is always "optional" - so, for example, the optional *second* occurrence is omitted in the cited example: *the meaning is that of a noun, not **that** of a continuous verb* (where either, both, or neither instances of the word ***that*** might be present / omitted).

Comment: Not the best sentence in the world.

Answer (score 0):

"the meaning is that of a noun" means that the type or kin=d of meaning conveyed in this situation is the kind normally provided by a noun, notmthe kind provided by a verb. Tis construction is common in academic writing.